# How to stop NVP forcing customers to sign up for account

Tags: paypal, paypal-nvp, nvp

I've had an NVP integration running for a year, and it's been great.

However, PayPal have now changed the page my customers see and the new style forces a user to create an account.

My customers are older people and don't want to sign up for an account. Previously they didn't have to

Is there anything I can do to make this optional again?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you're seeing?  The new pages still provide guest checkout, but sometimes it's not as prominent as the old pages.

Comment: [Sure](http://postimg.org/image/4clsrmhzf/) I have scrolled around and I just can't see anything to do a guest checkout. Very frustrating as it used to be there.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried from a non-mobile device to see if the experience is different?

Comment: Interesting, on desktop it seems to be a bit more random.  
i get the welcome screen [link](http://postimg.org/image/sdcb27s6j/)
then I get one of the two following screens  
[Screen 1](http://postimg.org/image/qgob5qzcb/)  
[Screen 2](http://postimg.org/image/bwbd5actn/)  
But interestingly I got to each screen by clicking on the "Guest checkout" button on the first link.  
  
Could it be that PayPal are testing forcing users to sign up?

Comment: What they are doing is split testing different versions of those checkout pages to see which one has the highest conversion.  Then, in theory, they'd stick with that one and start split testing other subtle changes.

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case. Thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to remember that Guest Checkout feature for Website Payment Standard and Express Checkout is not guaranteed for every transaction.
To control the risk for merchant, PayPal may close the guest checkout function for some special countries or districts buyers and the buyer will be asked to create a PayPal account.

If possible, please consider using the PayPal Payment PRO product line, where merchants can accept Credit Card directly within their own website.

Comment: Does that have PCI implications? I'm trying my hardest to avoid getting myself into PCI scope.

Comment: It does, but all you need to do is get an SSL certificate installed on the site and make sure you are not saving any credit card details in your database, in log files, or anywhere.  Also, PayPal offers direct credit card processing with the REST API now, too, and you don't need Pro for that.  I still prefer Pro personally, but it costs $30/mo where-as the REST option is free.